# Woo Testimonials Wordpress Plugin CSS No Longer Working Properly

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the Woo Testimonials Wordpress plugin to create testimonials. Unfortunately after a recent update this is no longer working properly.
The back quote on each of the testimonials is missing and the author citation is overlapping with quotation.

Does anybody know how to solve this formatting issue? Especially not sure how to bring the back quote back.

http://posturemedic.com/list-testimonials/

So far I add in the CSS below, to remove extra space and additional quotations that appeared: In the second one I just added the !important comment.

```
blockquote {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none !important;
}
```

Thanks,
Aleks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

- Adding `clear:both;` to the `.widget_woothemes_testimonials .quote` style
- Change the margin to `4em` to the `.widget_woothemes_testimonials .quote` style
- Create a style called `.quote p` and add `margin: 0;`
- Remove the bottom margin from the `.widget_woothemes_testimonials .quote .testimonials-text` style.

Applying the above should turn:

[image]

into

[image]

The styles would be:

```
.widget_woothemes_testimonials .quote 
{
    background: url('images/quote-testimonials.png') no-repeat top left;
    background-position: 0 3%;
    margin: 0 0 4em;
    clear: both;
}

.quote p 
{
    margin: 0;
}

.widget_woothemes_testimonials .quote .testimonials-text
{
    margin: 0 0 0 2.618em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: "Georgia";
    font-style: italic;
}
```

You can adjust the margins to display it differently.

You can also send the developer of the plugin a message to make them aware of the problem and they might fix it in the plugin itself in the next update.

Comment: Very cool. Do you have any idea how to bring back the quotation mark after the quote. Ex. " Testimonial "?